# Install scikit-learn for python3 very slow

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to install scikit-learn to be used in python3 on Jetson xaiver with ubuntu. When I ran:

`sudo pip3 install scikit-lear`

It stopped at

`Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
 Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ...`

And never finished. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```